# How do I create the init for a UIViewController subclass that I create programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

Say my `UIViewController` has two properties, `var animal: String` and `var color: UIColor`.

How do I create a custom `init` so I can easily create this in code?

I want to have:

```
init(animal: String, color: UIColor) {
   self.animal = animal
   self.color = color
}
```

But I get a compiler error that I'm not using the designated initializer. What am I doing wrong/how should I be doing this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `super.init()` after you set those properties. That should do the trick. Your method should look like this:

```
init(animal: String, color: UIColor) {
   self.animal = animal
   self.color = color
   super.init()
}
```

Comment: Usually in Swift, the super.init should be called last.

Comment: super.init() is not a designated initializer of UIViewController